# Electron: Get folder structure from client side

Tags: angular, desktop-application, electron

I am developing Angular2+Electron desktop application. As boilerplate I took simple example [Angular2 + Electron](https://github.com/auth0-blog/angular2-electron)

I need to get folder structure by *drag & drop* folder to the area. I found the way how to get information about folder once it dropped to area. Now need to get folder structure with a help of this info. Here is an example of returning object:

```
{
  lastModified: 1460044264000,
  lastModifiedDate: "Thu Apr 07 2016 18: 51: 04 GMT + 0300(EEST)",
  name: "dna",
  path: "/Users/myUser/Pictures/folder",
  size: 340,
  type: "",
  webkitRelativePath: ""
}
```

Any information on this issue will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all use [fs stats](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats) to check if that is a directory.

Then use [fs node module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) to read available files and folders in the folder.

**UPDATE**

If you use webpack as builder be sure to set up [`target: "electron-renderer"`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/quick-start.md#renderer-process) as mentioned in [webpack docs](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/Configuration#target).

TS would complain at `import * as fs from 'fs'`.

**First way** to solve this issue is to add `declare var require:any` and use `const fs = require('fs')` - ugly hack.

**Second** is to add node typings `typings install dt~node -GS`, configure `tsconfig.json` as:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "filesGlob": [
    "./src/customDefinitions.d.ts",
    "./src/app/**/*.ts",
    "!./node_modules/**/*.ts",
    "typings/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

And use `import * as fs from 'fs';`